# Can you "solve" any equation with 2 variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here on [Stack Exchange Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com) are many questions about "How can you solve this equation?". That made me wonder if you *can* solve any equation with two variables. What I mean with "solve" is not something like $x=[some\ number]$, $y = [some\ number]$ but $x = [some\ term\ with\ y\ in\ it]$.

Is this possible for any term with two variables? Why / Why not? What are the limitations of the equation to be "solvable" as described?

If the answer to this question is "yes", for how many variables does this work? $x = [some\ term\ with\ the\ other\ variables\ in\ it]$

Comment: Not sure about the tags to use.

Comment: Feel free to ask me if anything is unclear.

Comment: If you take something simple like $y=\sin(x)$...  In some sense $x=\sin^{-1}(y)$, but $\sin^{-1}$ was defined as the thing that makes this solvable.  Insofar that you can always define new functions, sure.  But this example also illustrates the domain/range issues you'll run into.

Comment: @Gaffney OK, it may not work if you have functions like $sin$. What if you use only addition, substraction, multiplication, divistion and potentisation? That's the part with the limitations required to make an equation solvable.

Comment: $y=xe^x$ is simple example with no way to solve for $x$ without defining a new function.

Comment: @Gaffney OK, yet another limitation ( ;-) ): What if you have a polynom?

Comment: Well again, even for $y=x^2$, the solution involves inventing a new symbol for the inverse (sqrt sign) and some domain/range issues.  I also believe that as a consequence of Galois theory, there are 7-degree polynomials $p$ for which $y=p(x)$ cannot be solved for $x$, even if you allow yourself radicals.

Comment: @Gaffney The "consequence of Galois theory" sounds like the right direction for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no in general. a good specific example is [the busy beaver function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver)  which is unsolvable in general for large enough x. This question seems to have a lot to do with undecidability where things can get complicated.  another example is the length of the collatz function for natural number x. there are no proven answers to this, if there were it would answer the collatz conjecture.

Comment: What if the equation is a polynom?

Comment: x^2+y^2=r^2  gives two solutions

Comment: I don't really want to get solutions, I want to have something like $x = [something\ with\ y]$. I'm not sure if I expressed this clear enough... So, here $x = \sqrt{r^2 - y^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, also for a polynomial, in two unknowns, we have general methods that gives a formal solution only if the unknow that we want to find has degree $n\le 4$ ( and the cases $n>2$ are not so simple), but if the unknown has degree $n>4$ it is very difficult to find a formal solution.  As an example, also a ''simple'' equation  as

$$ x^7y^7-7x^5y^5+3x^3y^2-9xy+10=0 $$ can be really impossibile to solve for $x$ or for $y$.

Comment: "really impossible" or really impossible **for a human**? I mean, this can get... ugly, but the question is not really whether if is _easy to find_ such an equation but if there exists one.

Comment: Do you mean solvable over the integers, over the reals or over something else ?

Comment: Speaking about polynomials we know that a solution always exists in $mathbb{C}$, but, in general, it cannot be expressed by means of radicals and other simple algebraic functions.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Does a solution always exist also in the case of multivariate polynomials ?